# Centreon/Icinga: command by services

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

I was wondering if it could be possible to recognize how a command is comformed with any services in Centreon? For example, which services contain the 'check_uptime' command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its possible using some sql magic queries but I'ver done that.

Though your question reminded me of this week's icinga2 api development where dependency tracking for objects has been implemented - this is important in case someone deletes a checkcommand at runtime, with many hosts/services depending on it. By default the api will deny removal, but cascading deletes would cause the entire dependency tree being deleted.

A side-effect from that development is the output of such object dependencies inside the status query for these objects.

Check the screenshot over here: https://twitter.com/dnsmichi/status/637586226711764992

It may not help you now, but with 2.4 being released in November.